# Codeigniter 4 shield - add admin prefix to login url

Tags: authentication, codeigniter

I've installed shield and have a created an admin route group.

When I go to example.com/admin I get redirected to example.com/login instead of example.com/admin/login.

How can I add the admin prefix to the login url/redirect?

I changed the Auth redirects but it's not working. Don't know what else to change.

Answer (score 0):

may be a routing problem like:

```
$routes->add("admin/login", "Admin\Login::index");
```